# How to stop a Word table wrapping text in cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a table in my Word document.

```
Dim t As Word.Table

Set t = doc.Tables.Add(doc.Paragraphs(1).Range, 3, 5, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitContent)

... Add text to cells in the table ...

t.Columns.AutoFit
```

The Autofit works fine for continuous text with no spaces, eg "MaryHadALittleLamb", but if I do have spaces eg "Mary Had A Little Lamb", the text becomes multi-line which rather ruins the look.

How do I stop Word wrapping the text and force it to put all the text on one line and AutoFit accordingly?

Comment: Did you try replacing Spaces with non breaking spaces (Chr(160))

Comment: @RedHare That certainly did the trick! Many thanks. Rather strange that I have to do this though ... you might think there would be flag somewhere.